# Use multiple Event Handlers for multiple elements in a forEach loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events

I want to add multiple event handlers on multiple HTML elements with the same class. I am using a forEach loop to achieve this. But for some reason it doesn't work as it should.
The first time I had a function to do this. I have multiple of images with the same class so I want to use a forEach loop to able to do an event at once. It's otherwise really annoying to type the same thing everytime.

This is before:

HTML

```
<img src="image.png" class="changeImg" onMouseOver="changeToGif(this);" onMouseOut="changeToImg(this);">
<img src="image.png" class="changeImg" onMouseOver="changeToGif(this);" onMouseOut="changeToImg(this);">
<img src="image.png" class="changeImg" onMouseOver="changeToGif(this);" onMouseOut="changeToImg(this);">

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
function changeToGif(x){
 x.src = "gif.gif";
}

function changeToImg(x){
 x.src = "image.png";
}
```

This is after:

HTML

```
<img src="image.png" class="changeImg">
<img src="image.png" class="changeImg">
<img src="image.png" class="changeImg">

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
let gifs = document.querySelectorAll(".changeImg");

gifs.forEach(gif => {
    gif.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      this.src = "gif.gif";
    });
    gif.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
      this.src = "image.png";
    });
});
```

SNIPPET:

```js
let gifs = document.querySelectorAll(".changeImg");

gifs.forEach(gif => {
    gif.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      this.src = "https://gifimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/tree-gif.gif";
    });
    gif.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
      this.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/31/10/03/big-tree-3443533_640.jpg";
    });
});
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/31/10/03/big-tree-3443533_640.jpg" class="changeImg">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/31/10/03/big-tree-3443533_640.jpg" class="changeImg">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/31/10/03/big-tree-3443533_640.jpg" class="changeImg">

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Why is this not working? It seems like I'm still missing something in the code. But I don't know what exactly what.

Comment: The first JavaScript block is not correct. `gif.gif` should at least be `"gif.gif"`. Can you make a runnable snippet (with toolbar) that we can run and reproduces the issue?

Comment: @trincot Ok sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were :

- moveover instead of mouseover
- this instead of gif in forech loop

```js
let gifs = document.querySelectorAll(".changeImg");

gifs.forEach(gif => {
  gif.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    gif.src = "https://gifimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/tree-gif.gif";
  });
  gif.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    gif.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/31/10/03/big-tree-3443533_640.jpg";
  });
});
```

```css
.changeImg {
  width:100px;
  height:100px
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/31/10/03/big-tree-3443533_640.jpg" class="changeImg">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/31/10/03/big-tree-3443533_640.jpg" class="changeImg">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/31/10/03/big-tree-3443533_640.jpg" class="changeImg">
```

Comment: Thank you I think that I was confused with `this` in my function. But your question helped!

Answer (score 0):

you are using `arrow function` `Arrow functions do not bind their own this, instead, they inherit the one from the parent scope, which is called "lexical scoping"`. in your case `this` belong to global scope and there is no `this.src` prop in `this` so convert it to normal function.

```js
let gifs = document.querySelectorAll(".changeImg");

gifs.forEach(gif => {
    gif.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
      this.src = "https://gifimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/tree-gif.gif";
    });
    gif.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
      this.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/31/10/03/big-tree-3443533_640.jpg";
    });
});
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/31/10/03/big-tree-3443533_640.jpg" class="changeImg"  width="20%" height="20%">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/31/10/03/big-tree-3443533_640.jpg" class="changeImg"  width="20%" height="20%">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/31/10/03/big-tree-3443533_640.jpg" class="changeImg"  width="20%" height="20%">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already had a premonition that `this` wasn't right. I'll keep an eye out for that from now on!

Answer (score 0):

In case there are multiple images not just one, use `data` attribute to toggle between *gif* and *image*

```js
let imgs = [...document.querySelectorAll(".changeImg")];
imgs.forEach((img) => {
  img.onmouseover = function () {
    temp = this.src;
    this.src = this.dataset.toggle;
    this.dataset.toggle = temp;
  };
  img.onmouseout = function () {
    temp = this.src;
    this.src = this.dataset.toggle;
    this.dataset.toggle = temp;
  };
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<img class="changeImg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtECC.jpg" data-toggle="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCkqa.gif"/>
<img class="changeImg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLhl9.jpg" data-toggle="https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2wFD.gif"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for this advanced method! I will use this in the future.